Not finding EPSG:2964 while setting CRS to work on Albers Equal Area for Alaska dataset
I want to work on Alaska dataset as guided by the QGIS manual that is provided in the portal for which I am providing the link - https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/getting_started.html
In the sample session part i.e., 5.3 section that you'll find after opening the link mentioned above, there's a step to set the CRS since the data to be worked with (Alaska dataset) is in Albers Equal Area.
But as I followed that step and opened the project properties and typed 2964 in the filter section, I'm not finding the corresponding predefined coordinate system which as mentioned in the guide should be NAD27/Alaska Albers with EPSG:2964. Is there anything that I have missed to enable that option or what should I do now?

Did you expand the Projected entry when using the filter? Can you show us a screenshot that shows us how your dialog for choosing the CRS looks like? Edit the initial question and paste it there. Type 2964 in the filter, not EPSG:2964. If you don't find it: what if you type NAD27 / Alaska Albers (exactly like this, including spaces)?

I drag-n-dropped the shapefiles from your link and QGIS automatically put them in EPSG:2964 exactly as the PRJ files directed. How are you loading the shapefiles?
